# why the output is not logically right?

Tags: json, python-3.x, if-statement

i'm trying to implement this code. here are the problems:
1. i want to use variable typ_transport in further coding not just inside if.(it does not recognize the variable.)
2. the logic seems to be right but when i change the values in  jsonStr (e.g. "walk" : true to "walk" : fasle ) the output does not print the right output.

Could any one help me with this? thanks

```
import json

jsonStr = '{"walk" : true, "bike" : false, "tram" : false}'
inputvar = json.loads(jsonStr)



if inputvar['walk'] == 'True' and inputvar['bike'] == 'False' :
    typ_transport='foot'

elif inputvar['walk'] == 'False' and inputvar['bike'] == 'True'  :
    typ_transport='bicycle'

class transport:


    if typ_transport=='foot':
        velocity=80
        typ='foot'
    elif typ_transport=='bicycle':
        velocity=330
        typ='bicycle'

    def __init__(self,typ,velocity):

        self.velocity = velocity
        self.typ = typ    

if  inputvar['tram'] == 'False' :

    radius= T*transport.velocity
    print (radius) 
else :
    print (typ_transport, 333)
```

Comment: `'True'` is a string and so is `'False'`. Removing the quotes should make this work a bit better.

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some problems in the code, so I'll try to point them out as I go through your questions

> 1. i want to use variable typ_transport in further coding not just inside if.(it does not recognize the variable.)

The reason why you can't access the `typ_transport` variable is that it's created inside the `if` statement. If you wish to access the variable later in the code, you would have to change the scope of the `typ_transport` into a global scope.

You can do this in two ways. First is creating a global variable before you start the `if` statement

```
typ_transport = ""
if inputvar['walk'] == True and inputvar['bike'] == False:
     typ_transport = 'foot'
```

The second way would be to create a global variable inside the if statement using `global` keyword. This way is highly discouraged since it is easy to lose the track of variables and their scopes.

> 2. the logic seems to be right but when i change the values in jsonStr (e.g. "walk" : true to "walk" : fasle ) the output does not print the right output

Aside from the spelling errors you got there, Python booleans are kept in `True`, and `False` (no single quote, first letter capitalized). When you use JSON module, it should parse correctly, but it's always good idea to double check.

Lastly, You are using class but it's not organized. Let's try to make it look little more tidier.

```
class transport:
    def __init__(self,typ_transport):   #utilizing global variable we created
       if typ_transport == 'foot':
            velocity = 80
            self.typ_transport = self.typ_transport
            self.velocity = velocity 
       elif typ_transport == 'bicycle':
             ......
```

Now to get the velocity when `typ_transport = 'foot'`

```
passenger = transport(typ_transport)      #creating passenger object
velocity = passenger.velocity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

jsonStr = ('[{"walk" : true, "bike" : false, "tram" : false}, '
            '{"walk" : false, "bike" : true, "tram" : false}, '
            '{"walk" : false, "bike" : false, "tram" : true},'
            '{"walk" : false, "bike" : false, "tram" : false}]'
            )
inputvar = json.loads(jsonStr)

class Transport:
    def __init__(self,typ):
        self.typ = typ
        self.velocity = None
        if typ == 'foot':
            self.velocity = 80
        elif typ == 'bicycle':
            self.velocity = 330
        elif typ == 'tram':
            self.velocity = 333

for var in inputvar:
    typ_transport = None
    if var['walk'] is True and var['bike'] is False:
        typ_transport = 'foot'
    elif var['walk'] is False and var['bike'] is True:
        typ_transport = 'bicycle'
    elif var['tram'] is True:
        typ_transport = 'tram'

    transport = Transport(typ_transport)

    print(transport.typ, transport.velocity)
```

This make more sense to me.
Feel free to change it, if I misunderstood your logic.

Comment: actually the jsonStr should be the exact format that i wrote , and the i want to use the value of typ_transport in other part of my code ( outside the if statement). so the format that i wrote should stay the same (e.g. class transport should not be changed) . is there a way to only do some minor adjustment to my orginal code and fix this problem ?